# Does this paper contradict the existence of non-relativistic quantum mechanics?

Tags: special-relativity, quantum-mechanics

The question in the title occurs when one reads this paper

> A. Dragan & A. Ekert, *Quantum principle of relativity,* 
>   [arXiv:1910.02780](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.02780),
>   https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/ab76f7

It seems as if all this time we were wrong in differentiating relativistic and non-relativistic quantum mechanics. If one takes the paper seriously, then relativity is inherently built inside quantum mechanics, and is the reason why particles move along various paths for instance. The math is solid, the arguments consistent, but... there is a catch right? I mean, we don't see relativistic effects in non-relativistic quantum mechanics (do we?).

I have read the paper like three to four times, gone over the maths a couple of times, and the only that thing screams wrong is the interpretation of the "existence of superluminal observers". We cannot guarantee nor falsify their existence(we are stuck on the subluminal side). It was not totally necessary to do that, and we just threw a few assumptions to rule them out, ***until this paper***. If the paper is correct, the superluminal side affects us in a more direct way than we have thought possible.

Tl;dr :This paper seems to say that relativity is the reason for the weirdness of quantum mechanics? How much trust can we put on this paper? Is there something fundamentally wrong? Or are we about to change some fundamental thinking of ours?

Anyone, who can throw some light into the matter, is highly encouraged to do so. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: On peer review: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/44126

Comment: Hi @rob. How do we know that this paper hasn't been peer-reviewed yet?

Comment: @rob Hi again. This paper has been published in the New Journal of Physics which publishes peer reviewed work. Here's the link https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ab76f7 .

Comment: This question (v3) seems to be of the form "I recently encountered [this article] online, is it correct?" [Such questions are off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/44126).  It may be possible to edit the question into a form that is a good fit for our site.

Comment: I would like to ask an off-topic question on this paper to @YuzurihaInori as I don't know how else I could contact you. Under equation (2), could you explain why $A(v)$ is *either* symmetric or anti-symmetric? I don't understand his reasoning. Aside from that, this paper is amazing...

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian It's because, suppose you flip x or t. Then it either flips x' or t' (both can flip, or only one can flip; it depends on how you flipped x and t) or does not flip anything. But doing so also flips the velocity, hence A(v) and thus A(v) also flips or it does not. These are your anti-symmetric and symmetric cases.

This is the argument the authors also use.